# How to res.redirect in nodejs in an angular+nodejs project

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I wanna redirect some get request to somewhere like `/hello-world` and I handle `/hello-world` address with angular4 route.

I wrote this but it won't worked properly :

```
app.get("/hi", (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/hello-world')
});
```

Angular says:

`Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/hello-world: 404 Not Found`

But when I go through `http://localhost:4200/hello-world` it give me 200 and show the proper result !

Comment: thats because you have not added a route handler for `/hello-world` on server so server dosnt know what to do at that path. `app.get('/hello-world',callback)`

Comment: @wrangler I handle it in client

Comment: do you have a route like `hello-world`

Comment: @iambatman Yes; as I said : But when I go through http://localhost:4200/hello-world it give me 200 and show the proper result !

Comment: whats the type of http request for `hello-world`

Comment: @iambatman what do you mean ? I don't request with a special type. I just wanna redirect !

Comment: I mean  its `get` or `post`

Comment: @iambatman :| absolutely a `GET`

Comment: make sure that your `hi` route is working fine

Comment: its may be route-precedence issue